# Identify intersecting polygons in single GeoJSON file with geopandas

Tags: python, geojson, shapely, geopandas

I'm trying develop some tools to manage what could be come a large GeoJSON file.  One such tool would identify intersecting features within the GeoJSON file.  In attempting to do this I tried a spatial join between two geopandas frames where the file is loaded, but every feature is listed because it intersects with itself.  Is there a way to get back a list of only the features that have an intersection with anything other than itself?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a unique ID from the GeoDataFrame (shapes), if needed you can make one, and then locate the ones that don't match IDs.

```
 together = geopandas.sjoin(shapes, shapes.set_index("UNIQUE_ID"))
 together.loc[together.UNIQUE_ID != together.index_right]
```

That will return a GeoDataFrame of all the polys that intersect with one another. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can get the id of the intersecting feature(s) of each feature by using, for example, the `apply` method and a list comprehension (to test each feature against all the features of the layer) and verifying that the features tested are not the same (`if x != gdf.geometry[i]` in the following snippet) but this isn't specifically efficient...
For example if I wanted to create a field `'id_intersect'` containing the id of the intersecting features I would probably do :

```
In [5]: geoms = gdf.geometry

In [6]: gdf['id_intersect'] = geoms.apply(
   ...:         lambda x: [i for i in range(len(geoms))
   ...:                    if x != geoms[i] and x.intersects(geoms[i])])

In [7]: print(gdf['id_intersect'])
0     []
1    [2]
2    [1]
Name: id_intersect, dtype: object

In [8]: gdf.plot()
Out[8]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x9f189d0c>
```

[image: Example layer]