# Intersects geoDataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, spatial, geopandas

I learned solution from question 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287150/identify-intersecting-polygons-in-single-geojson-file-with-geopandas][1]

i got a geoDataFrame of zid which intersect, but, when i test  on-by-one, they don't intersect. Why? 
 I try solution from answer1 and 2, but the result the same. 
zones 514, 519 have common border

```py
admzones = admzones[['zid', 'geometry']]
together = geopandas.sjoin(admzones, admzones.set_index('zid'))
together.loc[together.zid != together.index_right]

# zid|geometry|index_right
# 519|POLIGON()|514
#...

...

geo1 = admzones[admzones['zid']==519]
geo2 = admzones[admzones['zid']==514]
geo1['interssects'] = geo1.intersects(geo2)
geo1['interssects']
#False

geo1['intersection'] = geo1.intersection(geo2)
geo1['intersection']
#None
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't share an example but IIUC, you need to turn off the *index-alignment* (`align=False`):

```
geo_519 = admzones.loc[admzones["zid"]==519]
geo_514 = admzones.loc[admzones["zid"]==514]

geo_519.intersects(geo_514, align=False).any() # True
geo_519.intersection(geo_514, align=False).astype(bool).any() # True
```

[image]

```
admzones = admzones[["zid", "geometry"]]
together = admzones.sjoin(admzones.set_index("zid"))

print(together.loc[together["zid"] != together["index_right"]])

#    zid                                           geometry  index_right
# 0  514  POLYGON ((0.40000 0.10000, 0.75000 1.00000, 1....          519
# 1  519  POLYGON ((0.60000 0.50000, 0.59904 0.48040, 0....          514
```

Your code is most likely showing a `UserWarning` such :

> `UserWarning`: The indices of the two GeoSeries are different.

From the [`intersects`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.intersects.html#geopandas.GeoSeries.intersects) and [`intersection`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.intersection.html) docs :

[image]

Used input :

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point

admzones = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    {"zid": [514, 519], "geometry":
     [Polygon([(0.4, 0.1), (0.75, 1), (1.5, 0.3)]),
      Point(0.4, 0.5).buffer(0.2)]})
```

Comment: in docs says: _We can also check two GeoSeries against each other, row by row. The GeoSeries above have different indices. We can either align both GeoSeries based on index values and compare elements with the same index using align=True or ignore index and compare elements based on their matching order using align=False_ bat my GeoDataFrame consists from 1 row and intersects has to works identically. Not?

Comment: ok, i figured it out. in geo1 index=0, in geo2.index=78. Thanks

Comment: i got, these two figures have a common border. how can I ignore the common border?

Comment: You're welcome but I think that would be better suited for a new question. Feel free to [open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) it.